# How to set parameters on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, parameters

Im sorry I wasn't sure of the terminology for this question but I hope you can understand and help me out. (Also if the terminology is wrong correct me for future reference..Thanks!)

I am trying to set parameters for my iOS game so that when you click either side of the screen the player will turn to that side.

The code I have works to make the player move although it is set to the whole screen therefore only goes in one direction...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{


    X = -7;
    Player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Player Left.png"];
}
```

What needs to be added so that ONLY when the user touches the left side of the screen does this code run.

Thanks in advance and I hope you understand.
I am very sorry for any wrong terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if touch point is in left side of screen.. e.g -

```
if ([touches count] == 1) {
     // one finger
     CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
     if (touchPoint.x <= [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width*0.50) {
            Player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Player Left.png"];
     }else{
        Player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Player Right.png"];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define your "reactable" area by defining a `CGRect`. Then try to define if the touch is inside by using `CGRectContainsPoint()`. Something like that (not tested) :

```
CGRect reactable = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10); // A square of 10 px
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(reactable, touchLocation)
   Player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Player Left.png"];
```